# Is there in R to find out multiple duplicated codes and keep one of them?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have the following data

```html
df1 <- read.table(text = " ID Location Place
12 A M2
11 C M2
 13 M M1
12 B M2
11 C M2
4 D M2
15 Z M1
 13 M M1
15 Q M1
", header = TRUE)
```

I want to keep both IDs if the locations are different. If the IDs and The location is the same, I want to remove one them. So the desirable outcome would be:

```html
ID Location Place
12 A M2
12 B M2
11 C M2
13 M M1
4 D M2
15 Z M1
15 Q M1
```

I have tried the following codes, but it does not produce the outcome of intrest

```html
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% distinct(ID, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Is it possible to get the outcome?Thanks for your help

Comment: have you try using `unique(df1)`?

Comment: `?duplicated` ...

Comment: Victo@ yes, but it does not give exactly the outcome of interest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try adding Location in your code? I think it should give what you want.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% distinct(ID,Location, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% arrange(ID)
```

Comment: So just add arrange to this code based on your requirement. I have edited the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

I presume that do you not care about which value of the variable `Place` is kept.. 
in this case it becomes a classic ranking problem, you can explore how you rank `Place`, but to do so randomly you use the following code:

```
require(dplyr)

df1  %>%  
  group_by(ID, Location) %>%  
  mutate(rank = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  filter(rank == 1) %>%  
  arrange(ID) %>% 
  select(-rank)
```

the output would look like this:

```
 # A tibble: 7 x 3
     ID Location Place
  <int> <fct>    <fct>
1     4 D        M2   
2    11 C        M2   
3    12 A        M2   
4    12 B        M2   
5    13 M        M1   
6    15 Z        M1   
7    15 Q        M1
```

Comment: in that case what logic would you want to apply? in the example that you give the only duplicates of `ID` and `Location` happen to have the same value for `Place`, let's pretend that didn't, which one would you rather keep?

Comment: ok, in that case you would `arrange` the data frame by `ID`, I edited the answer.